# Cannot retrieve latest records from database (overflow?)

Tags: mysql

Working with a huge datatable of 141,749 rows containing a timestamp.

I've been storing data in this table for 2 years, but now I cannot 'see' the latest records since 11-02-2014.

I can still retrieve the latest data using php or python, but using mysql in the commandline or using phpmyadmin won't show me the latest ID's or timestamps of the stored data.

Anyone has an idea where this is coming from? I've never seen it before.

**OS:** Scientific Linux 6.4

**Apache:** Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Comment: You mean you retrieve _all_ lines in one go? Or do you use an `offset` and a `limit` in your queries?

Comment: use sort in your query to be accurate. the only difference showing the result in CLI and PHP is the readability IMO

Comment: @arkascha No, just retrieving by ordering on ID(primary key) in phpmyadmin, or using mysql-commandline, showing the last 30 records.